# Running a Python script with custom module import from Java

Tags: java, python, eclipse, module, spacy

I want to trigger the execution of some commands from a python module from Java. My script is executed without error messages, but it has no effect. The code I'm using from Java is as follows:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", "nerDemoTP/python/spacy_test.py");
pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
Process p;
try {
p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();
} catch (IOException e1) {
...     }
```

It works if my .py file contains only print('hello world'), then I see it in the Eclipse console. But what my python script is supposed to do:

```
from SpacyNER import SpacyNERExtractor
ner_extractor = SpacyNERExtractor('medium', 'sentences_nyt_200.txt')
annotated_df, entities_dict = ner_extractor.generate_extractions()
ner_extractor.store_predictions('test.csv')
print('spacy extractions done!')
```

And my SpacyNER module is defined as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import spacy
import en_core_web_md
import en_core_web_lg
import operator
import time
import re

class SpacyNERExtractor:

def __init__(self, model, text_file):
    if model == 'medium':
        self.spacy_model = en_core_web_md.load()
    else:
        self.spacy_model = en_core_web_lg.load()
    self.sent_df = pd.read_csv(text_file, sep='\n', header=None, error_bad_lines = False)
    self.sent_df.columns=['sentence']

def set_new_sent_df(self, df_new):
    self.sent_df = df_new


def store_predictions(self, file_name):
    self.df_predictions_spacy.to_csv(file_name,sep="#", index=False)
...
```

It has to do something with the import of the custom module, but I don't know how to deal with this problem. Also when I execute the script from the command line, i.e. python3.6 spacy_test.py, it works. 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are your python packages such as spacy or pandas installed in a virtual environment? or in your local machine? I'm struggling with a similar issue :/